# Using a list comprehension to look up variables works with globals() but not locals(). Why?

Tags: python

I am updating a project from python 2.7 to python 3.6.

I have a list comprehension that looks up variables from locals which worked in python 2.7.  It only works in python 3.6 when I switch to using globals.

Below is a toy example to illustrate the issue.

The relevant code is:

```
(A,B,C) = (1,2,3)
myvars = ['A','B','C']
```

If I execute the following code:

```
[locals().get(var) for var in myvars]
```

the return value in python 3.6 is:

```
[None, None, None]
```

However, the return value in python 2.7 is:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

If I execute the following code using globals:

```
[globals().get(var) for var in myvars]
```

then I get the same result in python 2.7 and 3.6:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Can anyone explain why the code using locals() no longer works in python 3.6?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we dissemble a more basic list-comprehension. we can see why this is happening:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("[i for i in range(10)]")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp>)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              9 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (10)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             18 GET_ITER
             19 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

So, on line `9`, we see that a list-comp actually makes a function which is called (you may be more used to this when using generators). Therefore, the function would have its own set of local variables as it is in a separate scope - thus yielding this unexpected behaviour.

---

Furthermore, as pointed out by `@juanpa`, [the "What's New in Python3" docs](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax) do explicitly state the following:

> list comprehensions have different semantics: they are closer to syntactic sugar for a generator expression inside a `list()` constructor, and in particular **the loop control variables are no longer leaked into the surrounding scope.**

---

Note also that there is a bug page on this: https://bugs.python.org/issue21161, however juanpa has convinced me that this isn't a bug for the reason that it is clearly documented to work this way!

Answer (score 5):

List comprehensions define a new scope in Python 3, which they did not do in Python 2. Simply put, `A`, `B`, and `C` aren't local variables in the list comprehension in Python 2.

As an aside, you probably should have been using an explicit dict `{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}` instead of separate variables all along. Now is a good time to fix that.